# What does the RNDBWM.exe process do?

Tags: windows-10

I have found the `RNDBWM.exe` process running on my computer and permanently takes one of the CPU cores (high CPU usage). The file description looks like below:

[image]

What is the process performs? Is this part of the Windows? Is removing this process will  significantly degrade the system performance?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I have found the `RNDBWM.exe` process running on my computer

> The process known as Rivet Networks Dynamic Bandwidth Manager belongs
> to software SmartByte Drivers and Services by Rivet Networks.
>
> Description: RNDBWM.exe is not essential for the Windows OS and causes
> relatively few problems. The RNDBWM.exe file is located in a subfolder
> of "C:\Program Files" (in most cases C:\Program Files\Rivet
> Networks\SmartByte).

Source: [RNDBWM.exe Windows process - What is it?](https://www.file.net/process/rndbwm.exe.html)

---

#### So what is `SmartByte`?

> **Smartbyte: What it is and how to remove it**
>
> - If you own a Dell PC and you're experiencing slow Internet speeds, then the Smartbyte utility may be to blame.
> - While the Smartbyte network service is useful on some Dell PCs, most users prefer removing it.
> - This article will give you a brief summary of what Smartbyte is, and how to remove it if you so desire.
> - Once you've finished reading, you can then decide whether to keep it or not.

...

> SmartByte is an application tool that automatically detects when you’re streaming video and gives that feed most of the available Internet connection.

Source: [Smartbyte: What it is and how to remove it](https://windowsreport.com/smartbyte-services/)

The link includes instructions on removing it.